# Смерть персонажа от enemy Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Имеется enemy под тегом "mouse" а также код, когда на "mouse" герой просто соприкасается любым способом, тот пропадает (mouse)
Код смерти "mouse":

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "mouse")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }

        else 
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы сам герой при горизонтальном столкновении от мыши погибал, но при этом герой мог убивать его прыгнув на голову.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнить расстоянии горизонтали и вертикали относительно мыши...

```
Vector2 MousePos = other.gameObject.transform.localPosition;
Vector2 HeroPos = gameObject.gameObject.transform.localPosition;
Vector2 DeltaPos = MousePos-HeroPos;
if (Mathf.Abs(DeltaPos.y) > Mathf.Abs(DeltaPos.x) && HeroPos.y > MousePos.y) {
    // Dead Mouse
} else {
    // Dead Hero
}
```